# Swift Initialiser Bug?

Tags: swift, initialization, infinite-loop

Edit: finished, duplicate of [Why doesn't this obvious infinite recursion give a compiler warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762234/why-doesnt-this-obvious-infinite-recursion-give-a-compiler-warning)
I believed that given the many clever warnings Swift has and also the designated initialiser system that it was reasonable to expect a warning, but this is wrong, as explained in the above.

I found this interesting example by playing around with protocol extensions, then realised it screws up structs as well.

```
struct WhatThe {
let a = 1
init(value: Int) {
    self.init()
}

init() {
    self.init(0)
}
}

print(WhatThe().a) //nothing is printed and the CPU goes nuts.
```

This is a bug isn't it? I understand this is an infinite loop, I'm just really surprised Apple allowed this.
This code has no warnings and builds fine, Playground even runs it.
I feel like this kind of thing was an obvious issue in the language to get rid of. It's fine in classes right?- because these are both convenience initialisers?

Comment: This is not a bug, but the special case of infinite loops that is _infinite recursion_, which is quite a common _developer error_, not in any way specifically related to Swift initializers. An even more simple initializer example is e.g. `struct Foo { init() { self.init() } }`, invoking (as for your example above) infinite recursion for when a `Foo` instance is initialized; readily comparable with the more well-known infinite recursion example of a recursive function just calling itself, say `func foo() { foo() }`, invoking infinite recursion when called; `foo()`.

Comment: Since the root of this question is not really Swift-language-specific, I suggest it be closed as duplicate of e.g. [Infinite recursion in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227093/infinite-recursion-in-c) or e.g. [Why doesn't this obvious infinite recursion give a compiler warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762234/why-doesnt-this-obvious-infinite-recursion-give-a-compiler-warning) (this latter one however closed, still contains a good answer w.r.t. compiler warnings an why these cannot catch infinite recursion).

Comment: Thank you both, that's solved it. I have voted to close it as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762234/why-doesnt-this-obvious-infinite-recursion-give-a-compiler-warning although the former http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227093/infinite-recursion-in-c isn't really the same question in my mind.

Comment: See my book, where I comment on this very issue: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_delegating_initializers Note the last paragraph of that section, starting with the words "Be careful not to delegate recursively".

Answer (score 2):

This is just a case of an infinite loop, your `init()` function calls `init(value:)`, which in turn calls `init()` again, and so on, so it never ends. Well, it will end when the stack overflows and will crash.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. I know this (it took me a few seconds) but I'm surprised this is allowed to compile!

Comment: To notice this loop, the compiler would have to execute your code, which isn't the compiler's job. Both functions are valid, that's why it compiles.

Comment: The issue is not that there is a loop, but that designated initializers are calling other designated initializers. Even stranger, if `let a: Int` is used, so that `a` has no default value, then the code *still* compiles even though `self` is referenced before `a` is assigned.

Comment: Compilers do not detect nor warn against infinite loops. To do so is to solve a very hard problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem